# Inconsistencies with setting cell widths manually

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Ok, so I'm taking on the age old task of creating a table that has a scrollable body with a fixed head, and I've written what seems like, to me, something that should work. Before I go into the problem, here's my code, along with a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mS5yB/) example of it.

Html:

```
<table class="table-scrollable" id="test">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Heading One</th>
            <th>Heading Two</th>
            <th>Heading Three</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two (and some extra long content to make the columns off)</td>
            <td>Three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>One</td>
            <td>Two</td>
            <td>Three</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Javascript (with JQuery)

```
$('table.table-scrollable').each(function () {
    $(this).before($('<div></div>').prop('class', $(this).prop('class')).prop('id', 'div_' + $(this).prop('id')));
    var newDiv = $('#div_' + $(this).prop('id'));
    newDiv.append($('<div></div>').prop('class', 'table-head'));
    newDiv.append($('<div></div>').prop('class', 'table-body'));
    newDiv.append($('<div></div>').prop('class', 'table-foot'));

    newDiv.children('div.table-head').append($('<table></table>').prop('class', $(this).prop('class')).append($('<thead></thead>').html($(this).children('thead').html())).append($('<tbody></tbody>').html($(this).children('tbody').html())));

    newDiv.children('div.table-body').append($('<table></table>').prop('class', $(this).prop('class')).append($('<tbody></tbody>').html($(this).children('tbody').html())));

    $(this).remove();

    // Now we need to set the widths of each cell in the header
    var HeaderItems = newDiv.find('thead tr th');
    var widths = new Array();
    HeaderItems.each(function (i, element) {
        // First, get the necessary width percentages
        widths[i] = (($(element).width() / $(element).parent().width()) * 100) + '%';
    });
    var css = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < widths.length; i++) {
        HeaderItems.eq(i).css('width', widths[i]);
    }
    newDiv.children('div.table-head').find('tbody').remove();
    CalculateScrollingBodyWidths(newDiv);
    $(window).resize(function () {
        CalculateScrollingBodyWidths(newDiv);
    });
});

function CalculateScrollingBodyWidths(divTable) {
    var styleId = divTable.prop('id') + '_style';
    var style = $('<style></style>').prop('id', styleId);

    var Headers = divTable.children('div.table-head').find('th');
    var css = "";
    var lastElementWidth = "";
    Headers.each(function (i, element) {
        css += 'div#' + divTable.prop('id') + ' div.table-body table tbody tr td:nth-child(' + (i + 1) + ') { width: ' + $(element).width() + 'px; }\n';
        lastElementWidth = $(element).width();
    });

    var pixelDiff = divTable.width() - divTable.children('div.table-body').find('tr').eq(0).width();

    css += 'div#' + divTable.prop('id') + ' div.table-body table tbody tr td:last-child { width: ' + (lastElementWidth - pixelDiff) + 'px; }\n';
    style.html(css);
    $('head style#' + styleId).remove();
    $('head').append(style);
}
```

And a small bit of CSS:

```
div.table-scrollable div.table-body {
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Here's an image of what it looks like in my actual project, where you can see the problem a little easier:

[image]

I have no idea why this isn't working. Even though I'm explicitly setting the width of the cell, something else is overriding what I'm telling it to do.

Do I need to set the display style on the cells to something else?

Comment: i can't see any problem in your code neither in your image.

Comment: If you look at the supplier column, the content below it is not in line with the column header.

Most of the columns are like this, but that one is the most noticable. It should be in line with the header just like the first column is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out!

All of the cells in my table had padding, which was somehow throwing off the widths that I was setting manually, even though the padding was the same for all of the cells (8px).

When I removed the padding, the cells were aligned, but they didn't look great, so I simulated padding by adding a space to the beginning and end of every cell in the table.

A better solution would be to possibly add a new column in between every column and on the ends, but I've got it where I'm ok with it for now.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if this is what you want. The default alignment of your header is center. Maybe you want it to stay left? Here's the solution.

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mS5yB/3/)

**CSS**

```
th{
    text-align:left;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that was just something I didn't include in the fiddle. It doesn't solve the problem in the long run, the picture I included of my app has the headers aligned left.